# Doxygen with Graphviz to document VHDL

Tags: doxygen, vhdl, graphviz

I don't manage to add a graphviz (@dot) to my doxygen documented VHDL files.
Can somebody provide some example code?

I would like to add fsm graphical representation to my code.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just write the dot-file manually:

```
digraph FSM {
    RESET -> IDLE
    IDLE  -> CALC [label="data_in = '1'"]
    CALC  -> DONE
    DONE  -> IDLE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. comment with `--!`;
2. start with `@dot` and stop with `@enddot`

Example:

```
--! @dot
--! digraph finite_state_machine {
--!     rankdir=LR;
--!     size="8,5"
--!     node [shape = circle];
--!     S0 -> S1 [ label = "010" ] 
--!     S1 -> S0 [ label = "000" ]
--!     S1 -> S2 [ label = "111" ]
--!     S2 -> S0 [ label = "101" ]
--! }
--! @enddot
```